# Native Base Input line height

Tags: react-native, native-base

I am using Native Base Component Input to create the TextInput, but the lineheight for display is broken and cannot show the complete word. The padding, margin, border, lineheight is not working in here.

Any people have this solution?  Thank You!

**Remark: only happen in android**

[image]

```
        <Text style={styles.inputHeader}>My Name</Text>
        <Item regular>
          <Input style={{height:35,marginBottom:0 }} />
        </Item>
```

Comment: Is it on android or ios?

Comment: @Pritish Vaidya android, ios is normally

Comment: Did you eject? This issue was resolved in Native Base 2.4.0

Comment: you should  post issue in native base github.. there you get quick solution here:  https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues

Answer (score 1):

I recommend wrapping it inside the `Form` tag in your *parent container* or your *wrapper*, for inheriting the styles assigned to it in your `Item`

```
<Form>
    <Label>My Name</Label>
    <Item regular>
        <Input style={{ height: 35, marginBottom: 0 }} />
    </Item>
</Form>
```

Answer (score 0):

give padding to input

```
{padding:2}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need of embedding inline styles

This is fixed with NativeBase

Try updating NativeBase in your project, and make sure you eject theme to find the fix